# springdoc: Incorrect XML schema for a REST-method that returns a list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, springdoc

I have such @RestController in my Spring Boot application:

```
package test.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    public static class Person {
        public String fullName;

        public Person(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "", produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public List<Person> getPeople() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Person("Name1"), new Person("Name2"));
    }
}
```

It returns such XML:

```
<List>
  <item>
    <FullName>Name1</FullName>
  </item>
  <item>
    <FullName>Name2</FullName>
  </item>
</List>
```

And such JSON:

```
[{"FullName":"Name1"},{"FullName":"Name2"}]
```

This structure almost suits me.

springdoc generate such openapi code:

```
{
    "/test" : {
        "get" : {
            "tags" : [
                "test-controller"
            ],
            "operationId" : "getPeople",
            "responses" : {
                "200" : {
                    "description" : "OK",
                    "content" : {
                        "application/json" : {
                            "schema" : {
                                "type" : "array",
                                "items" : {
                                    "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/Person"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "application/xml" : {
                            "schema" : {
                                "type" : "array",
                                "items" : {
                                    "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/Person"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components" : {
        "schemas" : {
            "Person" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "fullName" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    }
                },
                "description" : ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. There is no problems with JSON, but for XML format there are no mentions of *List*/*item* tags and error in swagger-ui for XML example "XML example cannot be generated; root element name is undefined". What is the right thing to do if the REST-method must return a list and openapi documentation is needed?
2. How to change the names of the *List* and *item* XML tags?

I tried to extend ArrayList, make the List<Person> a field of my class, use various annotations, but did not achieve the desired effect (subject to saving the desired response structure).

Answer (score 0):

My nearest solution after many tests — add wrapper class and a number of annotations:

```
package test.controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Person")
    public static class Person {
        public String fullName;

        public Person(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Persons")
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Persons")
    public static class PersonsList {
        private final List<Person> persons;

        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Person")
        public List<Person> getPersons() {
            return persons;
        }
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "", produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public PersonsList getPeople() {
        return new PersonsList(Arrays.asList(new Person("Name1"), new Person("Name2")));
    }
}
```

But JSON structure has changed: the list is now in a field `Persons`.